# puppeteer: clicking button in shadowroot

Tags: typescript, jestjs, puppeteer, web-component, web-component-tester

I'm having difficulties with actions on elements in shadowroot in my test context. Lets say I have a web component `<my-component />` and it contains a button `<input id="my-button" type="submit" />`

From console in chrome, I can do the following:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('my-component')[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('#my-button').click()
```

Im struggling doing the same with puppeteer.

```
  it('should click the button', async () => {
    await page.goto(`https://localhost:${port}`, {
      waitUntil: ['networkidle0', 'load'],
    });

    await page.$eval('my-component', (el: Element) => {
      el.shadowRoot.querySelector('#my-button').click();
    });
  });
```

Clicking the button should fire an http request to my server that retrieves some data which I then want to assert on in the dom. The request never fires. Suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to this comment from the [Puppeteer Team](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/858#issuecomment-438540596) the right way is to use JS path:

> In Chrome 72 (current Canary) we introduced a new option - "Copy JS Path", located right next to the "Copy Selector" option:
>
> [image: aaa]

Example using JS path:

```js
    it('should click the button', async () => {
      await page.goto(`https://localhost:${port}`, {
        waitUntil: ['networkidle0', 'load'],
      });
    
      const button = await (await page.evaluateHandle(`<JS-path-here>`)).asElement();
      button.click();
    });
```

Comment: Downvoted because as a developer this answer is not useful

Comment: Thanks, this did expose the shadow DOM. Now you can also use 'pierce' like so `const the_elem = await elem_parent.$('pierce/div.the_elem');`

Comment: The page I'm trying to copy the `JS Path` has the option greyed out on Chrome.

Comment: This just returns: `Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')` for me. :(

Comment: `button.click();` should be `await button.click();`. OP hasn't shared a [mcve], but what they're doing looks OK. I don't recommend using [browser-generated selectors](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors). See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68540701/6243352) on working with shadow roots in Puppeteer, which has links to many other resources. `pierce/` is a great suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is solved with [P selectors in Puppetteer](https://pptr.dev/guides/query-selectors/#-and--combinators).

In this case you could use `page.click('>>> #my-button')`. The `>>>` Allow you to select stuff in shadowRoots.

I know this issue is old, but I needed this and this issue still pops up on searches.